# Dynamic version from git with go get

Tags: git, go, build, version

I'm using git tags to inject versions in my go programs, e.g. in a `Makefile`:

```
VERSION = $(shell git describe --always --dirty)

github_pki: main.go
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux \
      go build -a \
          -ldflags="-X main.version=$(VERSION)" \
        -installsuffix cgo -o $@ $<
```

Where `version` is defined in `main.go` as:

```
var version = "undefined"
```

This works great using `make`, but not when using `go get` or `go build`. Is there a way to make this `ldflags` work without using an external build system (i.e. with `go build`/`go get`)?

Comment: Not according to the documentation. However you can use the [ident git attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_ident_code) to at least add the git hash of a file into the file.

Comment: With Go 1.13: `go version -- myExecutable` will print dependencies version information.

Answer (score 8):

From [issue 22147 `cmd/go`: Make it easier to embed compiled git SHA into binary](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22147#issuecomment-455684492) , you now have (with Go 1.12+, Q1 2019, 2+ years later) an alternative for the dependencies (not yet for your main program).

So you still need `-ldflags` to record the version of your sources.
But not to record the version of your dependencies: that is now available.

> As of Go 1.12, you can get the versions of all modules compiled into the binary (in module mode) using [`runtime/debug.BuildInfo`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#BuildInfo).
>
> If the version in use is a pseudo-version, it also includes the first dozen or so characters of the VCS commit ID.

```golang
// BuildInfo represents the build information read from the running binary.

type BuildInfo struct {
    Path string    // The main package path
    Main Module    // The main module information
    Deps []*Module // Module dependencies
}

// ReadBuildInfo returns the build information embedded in the running binary. 
   The information is available only in binaries built with module support. 

func ReadBuildInfo() (info *BuildInfo, ok bool)
```

This comes from [commit 45e9c55](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/45e9c5538b3956d98ef0337fc19ed8d45eb17090):

> ### runtime/debug: add API to read module info in binary
>
> When module is enabled, the go tool embeds build information related to the module in the binary including the dependencies and the replace information (See
>   [`src/cmd/go/internal/modload#PackageBuildInfo()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5538a9a34fc4e395967c0233aab5bdde0cebbf9b/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/build.go#L186), from [commit f7248f0](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f7248f05946c1804b5519d0b3eb0db054dc9c5d6)).
>
> The newly introduced `ReadBuildInfo` reads the information and makes it accessible programmatically.

You can see it used in [issue 26404: "cmd/go: export module information for binaries programmatically"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26404)

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime/debug"

    "github.com/kr/pretty"
)

func main() {
    bi, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo()
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("!ok")
    }
    pretty.Println(bi)
}
```

You get:

```sh
&debug.BuildInfo{
    Path: "foo.to/v",
    Main: debug.Module{
        Path:    "foo.to/v",
        Version: "(devel)",
        Sum:     "",
        Replace: (*debug.Module)(nil),
    },
    Deps: {
        &debug.Module{
            Path:    "github.com/kr/pretty",
            Version: "v0.1.0",
            Sum:     "h1:L/CwN0zerZDmRFUapSPitk6f+Q3+0za1rQkzVuMiMFI=",
            Replace: (*debug.Module)(nil),
        },
        &debug.Module{
            Path:    "github.com/kr/text",
            Version: "v0.1.0",
            Sum:     "h1:45sCR5RtlFHMR4UwH9sdQ5TC8v0qDQCHnXt+kaKSTVE=",
            Replace: (*debug.Module)(nil),
        },
    },
}
```

> If you build the binary in module mode from outside of a module using 1.12 ([#24250](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24250)), then you'll pick up all of its version information.
>
> but the reported version of the binary is always **`(devel)`** at the moment. Even if it is committed and tagged

So the main issue remains: [issues/29814 "`cmd/go`: use version control to discover the main module's version? "](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29814).

> When a binary is build from within a module's source tree, the output from `runtime/debug.ReadBuildInfo` currently reports that module as having version **`(devel)`**.
>
> If the source tree is a pristine checkout from a version-control system — or is within the (read-only) module cache — we could instead interrogate the version-control system to find the corresponding version or pseudo-version to embed.
>
> However, that has a couple of caveats:
>
> 1. It would require us to run VCS commands within the user's source tree. Historically, running VCS commands has been a source of entirely too many go command vulnerabilities, so we would really like to avoid issuing VCS commands except when they are absolutely necessary.
> 2. Given a commit, we can produce a pseudo-version for that commit, but we can't tell whether that commit has been published to the origin.
>      It would be nice to preserve the invariant that only published versions are advertised in debug info, but that may incur an extra network fetch.
> 3. Within a module, we apply that module's replacements and exclusions, and the user's VCS checkout may also have applied some transformations.
>      `(devel)` currently provides a clue that those module-specific changes are in effect: if we were to indicate an explicit version instead, we would need to provide some way to indicate that replacements and exclusions were applied.

---

[Go 1.13](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.13#go-version-exe) (Q3 2019) includes:

> The [`go version`](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Print_Go_version) command now accepts arguments naming executable and directories.
>
> - When invoked on an executable, `go version` prints the version of Go used to build the executable.
> - **If the `-m` flag is used, `go version` prints the executable's embedded module version information, if available.** ([`runtime/debug#BuildInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#BuildInfo))
> - When invoked on a directory, `go version` prints information about executable contained in the directory and its subdirectories.

Answer (score -1):

Is the following that you want?

```
VERSION=`git describe --always --dirty`; \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux \
    go build -a \
        -ldflags="-X main.version=$(VERSION)" \
        -installsuffix cgo -o github_pki main.go
```